# nexmo: forward to application and callers number

Tags: vonage

We have 3 options to connect to get inbound call.

1. Forward to Phone
2. Forward to application
3. Forward to SIP

**Forward to Phone:** When we call LVN then provided number gets call and callers number is seen in incoming call.

**Forward to application:** When we call LVN, then it goes to answer URL webhook. From answer url webhook, we provide connect ncco to call to my number. This time I am seeing LVN number in incoming call.

So is there any way in "Forward to application" method, that we will be able to see callers number in incoming call.

Comment: Or Is there any way to get event callback URL when using "Forward to Phone" option

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can forward the number of the incoming call by dynamically generating the NCCO when the call comes in and setting the `from` field in the `connect` action.

There are some examples in different coding languages [available on the Nexmo developer portal](https://developer.nexmo.com/tutorials/call-tracking) and check the [NCCO reference on connection actions](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/ncco-reference#connect) for exact examples but in a nutshell set the "`from` field at the same level as the `action` and `endpoint` fields in the NCCO response to contain the "to" number that is in the GET parameter of the incoming webhook to your answer_url.

Hopefully that makes sense, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Lorna, but we can set NCCO when we do "Forward to application" not for "Forward to Phone" as I said in my question. When I do forward to Phone, then my answer or event webhook url are not called. Only status webhook is called after call is completed.

Comment: Also in "Forward to Application", NCCO documentation says to set LVN in from field. In this case destination user sees LVN number. When I tried to set any other number in it, then destination user see some different kind of (+401 or similar kind)  numbers.

Comment: Take a look at the events that will cause webhooks to the event URL: https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/webhook-reference#event-webhook  - the answer webhook will be called when the incoming call comes in, not when you connect to another phone. The "from" field is an interesting question, there may be some geographical restrictions on only using numbers that you own. I suggest that Nexmo support would be the best people to advise on the specifics of that.

Comment: Thanks Lorna, I will try to connect to nexmo support on this. But just wanted to let you know that when we do "Forward to Phone", that time answer webhook or event webhook is never called.

answer webhook and event webhook is called for "Forward to Application"

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. When a call comes in to a Nexmo number, the answer webhook will be called, and then events on the resulting call will be sent to the event webhook. The answer URL isn't called if you connect to an application, it is only for what to do when a phone call comes in to Nexmo ... hopefully that makes sense!